# How to convert acceleration projection to angle?

Tags: kinematics, reference-frames, acceleration, vectors

[See a simple webpage here](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/accelerometer-info), for an object, if one know the acceleration in three direction $\hat  x, \hat y,\hat z$, one could extracted two of the angle of the object between the plane that's normal to the gravity.

I suddenly had a hard time to picture how that was done. Could you explain to me how they calculated the expression for angle AX and AY?

Comment: What is AX supposed to be the angle between?

Comment: *two of the angle of the object between the plane that's normal to the gravity* That doesn’t really make sense.

Comment: @G.Smith Sorry, I meant in 3 space. The plane was uniquely determined by the nonzero vector,i.e. I meant the "sea level" of which the gravity was in direction of the normal vector. Not sure how exactly to say it.(The plane perpendicular to the gravitational acceleration?)

Comment: Lookup cartesian to spherical coordinate transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there is a coordinate system (x, y, z), and you would like to work out the angle between the x-axis in your coordinate system and the ground on the Earth (reasoning will be similar for other axes).

You are given the components $f_x, f_y, f_z$ of the gravitational force along each axis (this is roughly what the accelerometer does).  Adding those components, as vectors, gives you the direction and magnitude of the gravitational force *in your coordinate system*: $\mathbf{F_g} = f_x \hat{x} + f_y \hat{y} + f_z \hat{z}$.

On Earth, of course, the gravitational force is perpendicular to the ground and pointing down.  If you now rotate your coordinate system to make the gravitational force point straight down the z-axis and record the rotation angles, then you can tell how your system was originally oriented, compared to the ground.

In particular, you can do this:

1. Rotate your coordinate system about its x-axis until the gravitational force has no component along the y-axis.
2. Next, rotate your coordinate system about the y-axis by some angle $-\alpha$ to get the gravitational force to be along the z-axis.

The angle $\alpha$ must have been the angle between the x axis of your coordinate system and the ground.

Relating this back to the web page you linked to...

After step 1 above, you have a vector with two components: one along the x-axis 
(which you will use the rotation in step 2 to eliminate), and one along the z-axis.

Since you have not changed the component parallel to the x-axis in step 1, its magnitude is still $f_x$.

The component along the z-axis must be whatever is left over, which is the combination of the $f_y$ and $f_z$ components before step 1.  The magnitude of the combination is $\sqrt{f_y^2+f_z^2}$, which is just applying pythagoras.

So now you want to work out the angle to rotate.  You have a right-angled triangle with one leg up the z-axis, magnitude $\sqrt{f_y^2+f_z^2}$, and one leg parallel to the x-axis, magnitude $f_x$.  The angle between the z-axis and the hypotenuse is $\alpha$ (the negative of the angle you want to rotate). The tangent of the angle between the z-axis and the hypotenuse is $\frac{f_x}{\sqrt{f_y^2+f_z^2}}$.  Take the inverse of the tangent ($\arctan$) to get $\alpha$.

(This would be better with pictures, but this is a bit time-consuming).

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot! So the fact that the generator of the rotation group do not commute does not affect the calculation?

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate, I haven't thought deeply about that, but since you leave the x-axis unmoved when you do the first rotation I think it won't affect the calculation of the angle between the x-axis and the ground.

Answer (score 2):

The Rotation matrix of the smartphone can be defined by its roll,pitch and yaw rotation.

Roll rotation angle $\phi$

$$R_x= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&0&0\\ 0&\cos \left( 
\phi \right) &-\sin \left( \phi \right) \\ 0&\sin
 \left( \phi \right) &\cos \left( \phi \right) \end {array} \right] 
$$

pitch  rotation angle $\theta$

$$R_y= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \cos \left( \theta \right) &0&\sin \left( 
\theta \right) \\ 0&1&0\\ -\sin
 \left( \theta \right) &0&\cos \left( \theta \right) \end {array}
 \right] 
$$

yaw  rotation angle $\psi$

$$R_z= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \cos \left( \psi \right) &-\sin \left( 
\psi \right) &0\\ \sin \left( \psi \right) &\cos
 \left( \psi \right) &0\\ 0&0&1\end {array} \right] 
$$

The Rotation matrix $R$ of the smartphone can obtain from this multiplication

$$R_1=R_x(\phi)\,R_y(\theta)\,R_z(\psi)\tag 1$$

or 
$$R_2=R_y(\theta)\,R_x(\phi)\,R_z(\psi)\tag 2$$

because the matrices are not commute  $R_1\ne R_2$

the acceleration vector is orientate to the z-axis

$$\vec{g}=\left[ \begin {array}{c} 0\\ 0\\ 
1\end {array} \right] 
$$

and the components of your  acceleration measurement  is:

$$\vec{F}_g=\left[ \begin {array}{c} {\frac {{\it fx}}{\sqrt {{{\it fx}}^{2}+{{
\it fy}}^{2}+{{\it fz}}^{2}}}}\\ {\frac {{\it fy}}{
\sqrt {{{\it fx}}^{2}+{{\it fy}}^{2}+{{\it fz}}^{2}}}}
\\{\frac {{\it fz}}{\sqrt {{{\it fx}}^{2}+{{\it fy}
}^{2}+{{\it fz}}^{2}}}}\end {array} \right]
$$

the solutions for the roll angle $\phi$ and the pitch angle $\theta$ are:

$$\vec{F}_g=R_1\,\vec{g}\quad \Rightarrow\quad \phi_1=-\arctan \left( {\it fy},{\it fz} \right) \quad \theta_1= \arctan \left( {\frac {{\it fx}}{\sqrt {{{\it fy}}^{2}+{{\it fz}}^{2}}
}} \right) 
\tag 3 $$

and

$$\vec{F}_g=R_2\,\vec{g}\quad \Rightarrow\quad \phi_2=-\arctan \left( {\frac {{\it fy}}{\sqrt {{{\it fx}}^{2}+{{\it fz}}^{2}
}}} \right) 
 \quad \theta_2=\arctan \left( {\frac {{\it fx}}{{\it fz}}} \right) 
\tag 4 $$

thus the solutions are not unique